# Google Analytics4 data transfers: ad_clicks and ad_impressions (from Google Ad Manager) are not sent to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-ad-manager

We do not have the GAM360 version and we want to transfer the raw data of ad_clicks and ad_impressions to BigQuery. I saw that is possible with Google Analytics 4.
However when I try to do that, it seems that every other event is sent but never the ad_clicks and ad_impressions.

Does anyone have an idea what would be the reason in this case please?

- I checked in the configuration and the desired events are not excluded there.
- Also I added another dummy type of events to test if the issue was a data limit or smt and the new dummy events do seem to be transfered.